# Is it possible to listen for changes in DynamoDB without polling?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I have a service (deployed on ECS) that needs to listen and react to inserts on DynamoDB table.

Currently I am reading the table every second, but I would like to lower the latency. Is there a way I can subscribe to changes in DynamoDB and be notified (via websockets, long polling or similar mechanism) when some record is inserted?

I have checked out DynamoDB Streams, but I couldn't find a way to subscribe to the changes there either. There is a [JS project](https://github.com/jfromaniello/dynamodb-subscriber) that does something similar, but it 
has a `"interval to poll"` setting...

Is it possible to listen for changes without polling? If yes, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems it is not possible. [This video](https://youtu.be/OjppS4RWWt8) explains the concepts very nicely, and it turns out that even Lambda doesn't really get "triggered" - it [polls](https://youtu.be/OjppS4RWWt8?t=761) the DynamoDB streams every 250 ms.

If a delay of 1/4 s is not a problem, one could setup events to traverse like this:

```
DynamoDB => DynamoDB Streams => Lambda => IOT => your app (via MQTT client or websockets)
```

Seems a bit convoluted though. Still, I would love to be proven wrong on this, so please comment if I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what DynamoDB Streams is for. Have you tried out [this tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.Lambda.Tutorial.html) to see if it gets you where you want to be as an example? Yes, it is in Lambda, but it could just as easily be deployed in a script somewhere else like you are trying to do.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, this is what I would have thought - however afaict Lambda is the only way to get notifications from DynamoDB Streams. I have added an answer with what I think is the current state of affairs.